# Mongodb MapReduce - Mongoexport missing column values

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce

Very new to Mongodb and MapReduce, but loving what I can do with it and getting on mostly ok. I am however having trouble exporting the results of a MapReduce to CSV.

Here's what i'm doing:

```
var mapFunction1 = function() {
                       emit({isrc: this.isrc, country: this.country}, this.amount_payable);
                   };


var reduceFunction1 = function(keyIsrc, valuesAmountPayable) {
                        return Array.sum(valuesAmountPayable);
                    };

db.sales.mapReduce(
        mapFunction1,
        reduceFunction1,
            { out: "sales_with_total_by_country_and_isrc" }
                )

db.sales_with_total_by_country_and_isrc.find()
```

When I run the find above I can see the results I want, ISRCs, Countrys and Values are all present.

I'm running my export as follows and as I say, this runs ok, all columns are present but I only have values in the value column, not ISRC or Country.

```
mongoexport --csv -d test -c sales_with_total_by_country_and_isrc -q '{value: {$ne: 0}}' -f "isrc","country","value" -o sales_with_total_by_country_and_isrc.csv
```

What am I doing wrong? As far as I can tell i'm passing the fields I want to the export with -f in the correct way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I sussed this out myself.

As, the resulting collection looked like:

```
{ "_id" : { "isrc" : "", "country" : "AE" }, "value" : 0.391081 }
```

I just needed to call `-f "_id.isrc","_id.country","value"` in my mongoexport call.

Hope this can help some others.

Comment: One of my values appears not to have summed but instead concatenated the separate values like this '0.00590100000000.0059010.133150000000.0053100.002960.043208000.00189'. Has anyone seen this before. It's only one line from nearly 200k. Orignal report was 5.2 million lines, so not bad considering but i'd like to fix it.